# ¿Por qué me sale que Google no esta habilitado en mi Firebase si ya lo habilite?

Tags: firebase, reactjs

En mi proyecto ya esta habilitado google pero por alguna razon no sale en el popup, aqui dejo el metodo google que estoy usando en la componente Auten.js.

```js
 google()
    {
        console.log("I am in google method.");
        let provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        let promise = firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);

        promise.then(result => {
            let user = result.user;
            console.log(result);
            firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).set({
                email: user.email,
                name: user.displayName
            });
        });
        promise.catch(e => {
            let msg = e.message;
            console.log(msg);
        });
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tengo otra consulta a veces me cierran la cuenta de stackoverflow y ya no puedo hacer preguntas, ya me paso con 3 cuentas y tuve que crear correos nuevos, no me gustaria que me pase con esta cuenta, que debo hacer? o a que se debe?.

Comment: Te falta todo el proceso de autorizacion de tu app en google.. lo hiciste? 
Aparte de eso, Crear nuevas cuentas no es algo que deberias hacer. Entiendo que hayas tenido problemas con tu cuenta anterior, pero para eso podias comunicarte con la pagina o buscar un moderador en el [chat] para que revisara que paso con tu cuenta

Comment: gracias entiendo, en el proceso de autorizado deberia pagar algo a google? o no es una subscripcion ni nada de eso verdad?

Comment: Es el proceso para que una app pueda acceder a OAUTH.. te dan una clave para que tu app acceda..

Comment: creo que lo dejare sin autenticacion de google porque me manda a una pagina que me pide mis datos y pagar algo jaja no importa solo iba a ser una forma extra de registrarse pero la convencional esta bien.

Comment: Agrega eso como respuesta entonces, asi la pregunta no queda abierta sin nada.

Comment: No deberias por que pagar nada para poder integrar un sistema de logueo con Google, podrias poner los pasos que realizaste para obtener ese error ? Como se genera? Como usas las credenciales? Como enlazaste tu proyecto a Firebase ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que lo dejare sin autenticacion de google porque me manda a una pagina que me pide mis datos y pagar algo jaja no importa solo iba a ser una forma extra de registrarse pero la convencional esta bien.
muchas gracias.

Comment: Estoy seguro que el problema solo esta en el API key que estas usando para authenticar con google